# No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_toRightOf' with value '@id/right_item_menu_fragment')

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to configure three fragments: one with the fixed width on the left, one with the fixed width on the right, and one in the middle that would take all remaining space. I searched for a solution, and followed suggestions that I found online, however when I try to run the app, I am getting an error:

**No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_toRightOf' with value '@id/right_item_menu_fragment').**

If I move the RelativeLayout id='canvas_fragment' after layout id='right_item_menu_fragment', then the installation is successful (no above-mentioned error), but the 'canvas_fragment' is not visible on the screen.

I searched for this error, and there are different reasons why it can be happen, but none of them applies to my situation. Many people have this error when using Eclipse, but I am using Android studio.

If someone can point out what I am doing wrong, help will be much appreciated.

Here is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     
android:id="@+id/canvas_layout"      
android:layout_width="match_parent"       
android:layout_height="match_parent">             

<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"       
    android:id="@+id/left_item_menu_fragment"      
     android:layout_width="@dimen/item_menu_width"     
     android:layout_height="match_parent"      
     android:layout_alignParentLeft = "true"     
    android:background="#cccccc">           

 </RelativeLayout>          

 <RelativeLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"      
        android:id="@+id/canvas_fragment"      
        android:orientation="vertical"      
        android:layout_height="match_parent"     
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_toLeftOf = "@+id/left_item_menu_fragment"       
        android:layout_toRightOf = "@id/right_item_menu_fragment"      
        android:background="#000000" >            

</RelativeLayout>                

<RelativeLayout 
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"       
       android:id="@+id/right_item_menu_fragment"       
       android:layout_width="@dimen/item_menu_width"      
        android:layout_height="match_parent"     
         android:layout_alignParentRight = "true"      
        android:background="#cccccc">          

</RelativeLayout>
                         </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Add a `+` in front of `id`. That is, `"@+id/right_item_menu_fragment"`. With your layout in that order, at that point, that ID hasn't been generated yet, which is what the `+` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run into this before and it seems to be a forward-reference problem. Try rearranging the relative layouts as follows so the middle section is defined last.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/canvas_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/left_item_menu_fragment"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/item_menu_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="#cccccc">
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/right_item_menu_fragment"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/item_menu_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="#cccccc">

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/canvas_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    <!-- layout_toLeftOf and layout_toRightOf were backwards. This is correct.-->
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/right_item_menu_fragment"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/left_item_menu_fragment"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</RelativeLayout>
```

What Mike M says is true as well. See [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource.html#idvalue) for details.

Comment: I tried it, and the "canvas_fragment" wasn't even displayed on the screen. Only the left and right fragments. However, I found how to display it using weight. I defined outer layout as android:weightSum="10", and gave corresponding layout_weights to each fragment: 1, 9 and 1

Comment: I just noticed that `canvas_fragment` is laid out to the "left of" `left_item_menu_fragment` and to the right of `right_item_menu_fragment` and that is backwards. It should be laid out to the "left of" `right_item_menu_fragment` and to the right of `left_item_menu_fragment`. Do you agree? It's easy to overlook.

Comment: Thanks, @Cheticamp, that was the reason that the canvas_fragment was not displayed. It's working now.